# opencart checkout not expand,just show the 6 steps

Tags: opencart, checkout, expand

Hi i have problem with opencart 1.5.6.4,my checkout dont like to expand and to show register or login when you proces to buy the product just,show the 6 step whit out to expand,The buttons at the one-page checkout are not expanding. If u visit this link: http://imeibox.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout u can see there is not button are not doing anything, so we cannot fill in any information or select any options. Is there a simple solution for this problem or is there bad coding behind those buttons?

kind regards
GEORGI

Comment: the website:www.imeibox.com,when you put the product in shopping cart and goo to chechout,the checkout jus no expabd for register or login,

Comment: There are some javascript errors. Try to solve them first. I hope it will work once you solve that errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks like it could be anything.

First thing that comes to mind,have you added a Jquery library to the **header.tpl** file recetly? if you have,there's your problem.

Try some checkups to see where the issue is coming from

**1:turn off the theme you are using and check the cart again**

**2:Turn off any new modules you have installed**

**3:check your error log,and see what you have there,dont forget to check the vqmod/logs**

usually that area of opencart works without a problem.so its either some code you did,the theme you are using or a bad module

**DO not forget to do a backup before you do anything**

Comment: Hi thank you innervisions,i try all,and is tha same,the error log is empty,vqmod is empty.i dont know what to do.thank you any way.

Comment: @Web8.us did you do anything before this error occured?

Comment: Hi thank you,to try to help me,i just install fresh copy of opencart 1.5.6.4,but i not test the new intstall,after install directly beamstore template:http://themeforest.net/item/beamstore-responsive-multipurpose-opencart-theme/8077443,and after install demo data with plugins incluided in the template.